# Should we access protected properties directly or with getters?

Tags: php

Should we access protected properties directly or with getters in PHP ?

I have two classes with one is the daughter of the other. In the mother, I declare certain properties as protected and I generate all getters for my properties. So, I can access and define those properties directly or via the getters, but I don't know if there is a better solution.

Example :

```
class Mother {

    private $privateProperty;
    protected $protectedProperty;
    public $publicProperty;

    /*** Private property accessors ***/   

    public function setPrivateProperty($value)
    {
        $this->privateProperty = $value;
    }

    public function getPrivateProperty()
    {
        return $this->privateProperty;
    }

    /*** Protected property accessors ***/   

    public function setProtectedProperty($value)
    {
        $this->protectedProperty = $value;
    }

    public function getProtectedProperty()
    {
        return $this->protectedProperty;
    }
}

class Child extends Mother {

    public function showProtectedProperty() {
        return $this->getProtectedProperty();   // This way ?
        return $this->protectedProperty;        // Or this way ?
    }

    public function defineProtectedProperty() {
        $this->setProtectedProperty('value');   // This way ?
        $this->protectedProperty = 'value';     // Or this way ?
    }
}
```

In the example, I know I can't access/set directly the private property, and that it's useless for public properties. But I can use both ways for the protected property. So, are there any standard to use ?

Comment: In the above code you might as well just create public properties...

Answer (score 4):

Best encapsulation is accomplished when you indeed use getters and setters also along a class hierarchy. This means: Attributes should be private and getters/setters are protected (if not public).

For example, if you want to log access to certain attributes, want to add a filter method or another check, the whole mechanism would be removed, if you just accessed those attributes in the derived class.

(Of course, there are situations where you would just make attributes public to make code shorter and because you know that the class is really just a data-holder... In that case, however, those attributes would still not be protected but simply public)

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question a while back on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181567/should-the-methods-of-a-class-call-its-own-getters-and-setters/181569#181569):

> I won't say which is better or worse, because that partly depends on your situation (in my opinion). But consider that your getters and setters may change implementation later, and bypassing them would skip that logic.
>
> For example, what happens if you add a "dirty" flag to some setter fields later? By calling your setters in your internal code you'll set the dirty flag without changing any other code. In many situations this would be a good thing.

You might need special rules, like maybe initialization code should skip using setters.  The most important thing is to pick an appropriate policy in your project and stick to it for consistency.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't even think about properties as having "a getter/setter". These two are different things. Properties store state, getters return values, setters modify the object state. Sometimes these *may* have very direct 1:1 correlations, but they need not have.

In fact, if all your setter does is `$this->foo = $foo` and the getter does `return $this->foo`, **make it a `public` property to begin with!** For all intents and purposes it already is. There's no point to having functions dress up this property, they do not in fact add any value.

For the sake of discussion, imagine a class like this:

```
class Foo {

    protected $timestamp;

    public function setStartTime($int) {
        $this->timestamp = new DateTime("@$int");
    }

    public function getElapsedTime() {
        return $this->timestamp->diff(new DateTime);
    }

}
```

This more clearly illustrates the disconnect between *state*, *state modification* and *value return*. The "setter" accepts an integer, the property stores a `DateTime` object, and the "getter" returns a `DateInterval` object. They don't really have anything to do with one another.

To bring this back around to your original question: If you know what *state* the property represents and when/how it may be modified and what rules the class expects this property state to adhere to, you may touch the property directly. If, however, you do not know a lot about the inner workings of the class and just want to interact with its *public interface* to get its results, use the accessor methods.

Comment: I don't understand, the two functions you show me as example are not really accessors. Those are functions that calculate something based on the property. In your example, if you want to access the $timestamp property from another class, how will you do it ?

Comment: That's exactly the point I'm trying to illustrate. Get rid of the idea that properties have certain methods which are exactly equivalent and interchangeable. If you do have an interchangeable accessor, you probably don't need it in the first place. If the accessor *does* something, the answer whether you want to directly access the property or get the result of the accessor should be self evident. My example is on the very extreme end, but that's on purpose. Try to view all property-accessor relationships like this example.

Comment: I understand your opinion but :
* Why the magic methods if we don't use the accessors ? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php
* And, I work with Doctrine/ Symfony2, and all entities have private property with accessors : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Entity/Post.php, why this solution ?

Comment: @john Magic methods mostly allow you to design an API which looks different than it's actually implemented. A very good example of a *good* use of magic methods IMO is SimpleXML. It *looks* like a regular object, but whenever you access any "property" a lot of magic happens behind the scenes. I *do not* think you should rely on magic methods very much for everyday objects.

Comment: @john Secondly, the advantage of having "dumb 1:1 accessors" is that it affords you the option of extending whatever is happening upon a property access later on. If you tell all your users to use `$foo->bar` directly, but later on you decide you actually need to run some code and would like everyone to use `$foo->getBar()` instead, you're pretty screwed. I'd allow that as one reason to use accessors from the beginning. However, again, **think of it like described above from the beginning**. You just need to get into that headspace. Then the OP's question is answering itself.